# How do I dynamically create a form and it event handlers without opening and closing the visual basic editor?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am developing an access application that needs to create dynamic forms and the associated event handlers for the controls on the form. I cannot build these forms on startup, they are created upon special conditions that are not known before hand. These conditions can change during the time that the application is used.

Unfortunately, when I create the form and the event handler, this does not happen in a "hidden state" so that the user is distracted in the (short) period when the form is created.

I'd rather have access create the form (and event handlers) in the background (or somehow hidden from the user). Is this possible?

Comment: You need to enable access to the VBE object model, and be prepared for writing code *that writes code*.

Comment: I belive that's what I have already done: I have a procedure in a module that, when called, modifies the form and creates the event handlers. I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind.

Comment: Roughly, yes; but if you need a *dynamic* form you'll need more than that - you'll have to *add VBComponent objects (forms) to the VBProject*, access their code module/code pane, write code there.... and then pray the VBE doesn't crash =)